# How do I set a unique primary key in Realm?

Tags: android, realm

How do I set a unique primary key in Realm in Android? The Realm documentation says I cannot use anything but String or int/long, so is UUID type is out of the question too? What if I have items with the same name?

e.g.

```
public class GroceryItem extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long        id;    <--- how can I make this unique without UUID?
    private String      name;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
} }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realm doesn't support any autoincrement for primary keys. Visit [docs](https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-primary-keys-tutorial/) for more information about this. So, you are to handle it by yourself.

1) Use should use UUID. You can also get long, int or String value from it:

```
long: UUID.randomUUID().getMostSignificantBits();
int: (int) UUID.randomUUID().getMostSignificantBits();
String: UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

2) Or you can query some data from your database and apply some rules to generate a new key. For example, query for the last element and increment it's primarykey. But that's not ideal way.

Comment: This is it, thanks Potapov. I also like the suggestion on how to overcome auto increment; what would you say is the ideal way?

Comment: Well, an ideal way is just to use UUID and generate it randomly

Comment: Oh I see thanks, I thought you meant there was a better way to implement auto increment :-) I misread, thanks again & have a good day.